# Joining multiple tables returns NULL value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have 3 different outcomes of CTE that I need to LEFT JOIN each other:

Main Table `@Policies` contains all `VehiclePolicyLimitsID` values:

[image]

`@LiabilityPremium`:

[image]

`@HiredPremium`:

[image]

As an example I mimic the results of CTE's into 3 table variables:

```
declare @Policies table (VehiclePolicyLimitsID int)
insert into @Policies values (2101891),
                             (2101892),
                             (2101893),
                             (2101894),
                             (2119235),
                             (2119236),
                             (2119237),
                             (2119238),
                             (2190860),
                             (2190861),
                             (2190862),
                             (2190863)
--select * from @Policies


declare @LiabilityPremium  table (Quoteid int, ClassCode int, VehiclePolicyLimitsID int, LiabilityPremium money)
insert into @LiabilityPremium values (728436,3199,2101892,1723),
                                     (728436, 23199,2101893,1855),
                                     (728436,68199,2101894,133),
                                     (741626,3199,2119236,0),
                                     (741626,23199,2119237,0),
                                     (741626,68199,2119238,0),
                                     (774168,3199,2190861,0),
                                     (774168,23199,2190862,0),
                                     (774168,68199,2190863,0)
--select * from @LiabilityPremium

declare @HiredPremium  table (Quoteid int, ClassCode int, VehiclePolicyLimitsID int, LiabilityPremium money)
                    insert into @HiredPremium values ( 728436,  NULL,   2101891,    25),
                                                     (741626,   NULL,   2119235,    0),
                                                     (774168,   NULL,   2190860,    0)

--select * from @HiredPremium
    select 
            COALESCE(l.Quoteid,h.QuoteID,'') as QuoteID,
            COALESCE(l.ClassCode,h.ClassCode,'') as ClassCode,
            COALESCE(l.VehiclePolicyLimitsID,h.VehiclePolicyLimitsID,'') as VehiclePolicyLimitsID,
            l.LiabilityPremium + h.LiabilityPremium as LiabilityPremium
    from @Policies p
    left join @LiabilityPremium l ON l.VehiclePolicyLimitsID = p.VehiclePolicyLimitsID
    left join @HiredPremium h ON h.VehiclePolicyLimitsID = p.VehiclePolicyLimitsID
```

But for some reason the outcome of LiabilityPremium is all NULL's:

[image]

I would expect the result looks like this with total LiabilityPremium = $3,736

[image]

Is any way to join somehow to receive desirable result?

Comment: This is because NULL plus **anything** is always NULL. In your query you could NULL in either side of that equation as they are both using a left join. Wrap them in ISNULL or COALESCE to prevent to the NULL.

Comment: @SeanLange answered your question I think but Just adding upvote because your question is formatted very well with data examples and executable script for examples.  Very nice to see.

Comment: Learned hard way :)  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `null` on either side of the addition operator will yield a result of `null`. You can use `ISNULL(LiabilityPremium, 0)` Example:

```
ISNULL(l.LiabilityPremium,0) + ISNULL(h.LiabilityPremium,0) as LiabilityPremium
```

or you can use `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`.

```
COALESCE(l.LiabilityPremium,0) + COALESCE(h.LiabilityPremium,0) as LiabilityPremium
```

---

### Edit

I am not sure if this is coincidence with this small data set or expected but **if** it is always expected that either `@LiabilityPremium.LiabilityPremium` or `@HiredPremium.LiabilityPremium` will always be null then there is no need to perform addition. Instead use `COALESCE` directly on those 2 columns.

```
COALESCE(l.LiabilityPremium, h.LiabilityPremium) as LiabilityPremium
```

Answer (score 2):

```
COALESCE(l.LiabilityPremium,0) + COALESCE(h.LiabilityPremium,0) as LiabilityPremium
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of

```
l.LiabilityPremium + h.LiabilityPremium
```

If any of the two is NULL, the expression is NULL.

This expression should fix it

```
COALESCE(l.LiabilityPremium, 0.00) + COALESCE(h.LiabilityPremium, 0.00)
```