# How to get time between calls in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the average time between phone calls per agent at one of our call centers. These are the queries I have thus far:

```
--This query gets all the agentIDs and their callstarts and callends, and as far as I know, attaches an incrementing row-number to them.
drop table #thuranin
SELECT AgentID, CallStart, CallEnd, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) AS rowInt
INTO #thuranin
FROM Main.CallRecord
WHERE DialerPoolManagementID is null and incomingcall = 0 
ORDER BY AgentID

--This query attempts to get the time between each call
drop table #ploto
SELECT nin.AgentID, (CAST(ISNULL(th.CallStart, 0) - nin.CallEnd AS float)) AS AverageTimeBetween
INTO #ploto
FROM #thuranin nin
LEFT JOIN #thuranin AS th ON th.rowInt = (SELECT MIN(rowInt) FROM #thuranin WHERE rowInt > #thuranin.rowInt AND AgentID=th.AgentID)

--This query should average the times by agent
SELECT agentID, AVG(ABS(AverageTimeBetween)) as avGTimebwn
FROM #ploto
WHERE ABS(AverageTimeBetween) > 20000
GROUP BY AgentID
```

However, this fails (hence why I'm here). It returns values in the -40000's, and I'm not entirely sure why. I need to get the average amount of time between a call end and a call start per agent.

I know that calls at the end of the day to start of the next day could be inflating that number, but I'm unsure of how to deal with that either.

Here's a sample hundred rows from the #thuranin temporary table, if it helps:

```
AgentID CallStart   CallEnd rowInt
NULL    2013-05-29 13:48:39.000 2013-05-29 13:57:20.000 139541
191 2013-05-29 13:50:16.000 2013-05-29 13:50:43.000 139581
NULL    2013-05-29 13:52:04.000 2013-05-29 13:52:46.000 139621
115 2013-05-29 13:53:20.000 2013-05-29 13:53:21.000 139661
190 2013-05-29 13:56:27.000 2013-05-29 13:57:59.000 139701
NULL    2013-05-29 13:58:46.000 2013-05-29 13:59:44.000 139741
171 2013-05-03 18:37:07.000 2013-05-03 18:37:14.000 139781
NULL    2013-05-03 18:39:49.000 2013-05-03 18:41:52.000 139821
107 2013-05-03 18:42:32.000 2013-05-03 18:42:38.000 139861
184 2013-05-03 18:45:38.000 2013-05-03 18:46:08.000 139901
NULL    2013-05-03 18:47:07.000 2013-05-03 18:47:57.000 139941
31  2013-06-14 15:22:02.000 2013-06-14 15:22:44.000 139981
31  2013-06-14 15:24:47.000 2013-06-14 15:25:16.000 140021
31  2013-06-14 15:29:10.000 2013-06-14 15:29:11.000 140061
31  2013-06-14 15:33:57.000 2013-06-14 15:34:06.000 140101
31  2013-06-14 15:41:32.000 2013-06-14 15:42:18.000 140141
172 2013-04-24 21:48:47.000 2013-04-24 21:51:45.000 140181
169 2013-04-24 21:50:42.000 2013-04-24 21:50:53.000 140221
65  2013-04-24 21:52:47.000 2013-04-24 21:52:54.000 140261
169 2013-04-24 21:57:49.000 2013-04-24 21:57:57.000 140301
NULL    2013-04-24 22:04:59.000 2013-04-24 22:06:11.000 140341
31  2013-06-20 14:37:45.000 2013-06-20 14:38:29.000 140381
31  2013-06-20 14:40:27.000 2013-06-20 14:41:09.000 140421
31  2013-06-20 14:44:05.000 2013-06-20 14:44:39.000 140461
31  2013-06-20 14:50:53.000 2013-06-20 14:51:17.000 140501
31  2013-06-20 14:58:52.000 2013-06-20 14:59:24.000 140541
31  2013-07-10 19:54:21.000 2013-07-10 19:54:31.000 140581
31  2013-07-10 20:01:24.000 2013-07-10 20:01:51.000 140621
31  2013-07-10 20:06:23.000 2013-07-10 20:07:14.000 140661
31  2013-07-10 20:09:46.000 2013-07-10 20:09:56.000 140701
31  2013-07-10 20:12:10.000 2013-07-10 20:12:49.000 140741
31  2013-07-10 20:14:45.000 2013-07-10 20:14:59.000 140781
175 2013-07-01 22:35:54.000 2013-07-01 22:36:14.000 140821
191 2013-07-01 22:42:29.000 2013-07-01 22:43:43.000 140861
175 2013-07-01 22:49:42.000 2013-07-01 22:49:57.000 140901
107 2013-07-01 22:59:39.000 2013-07-01 23:00:48.000 140941
191 2013-07-01 23:09:52.000 2013-07-01 23:10:52.000 140981
NULL    2013-04-02 15:47:14.000 2013-04-02 15:48:06.000 141021
NULL    2013-04-02 15:48:48.000 2013-04-02 15:49:07.000 141061
NULL    2013-04-02 15:50:03.000 2013-04-02 15:50:53.000 141101
196 2013-04-02 15:52:05.000 2013-04-02 15:52:52.000 141141
NULL    2013-04-02 15:53:03.000 2013-04-02 15:53:06.000 141181
NULL    2013-05-08 16:17:54.000 2013-05-08 16:18:10.000 141221
140 2013-05-08 16:19:53.000 2013-05-08 16:20:05.000 141261
188 2013-05-08 16:21:34.000 2013-05-08 16:38:04.000 141301
NULL    2013-05-08 16:23:22.000 2013-05-08 16:25:02.000 141341
NULL    2013-05-08 16:25:16.000 2013-05-08 16:27:02.000 141381
31  2013-07-01 23:13:21.000 2013-07-01 23:14:24.000 141421
31  2013-07-01 23:24:23.000 2013-07-01 23:25:23.000 141461
31  2013-07-01 23:40:14.000 2013-07-01 23:40:50.000 141501
31  2013-07-01 23:44:35.000 2013-07-01 23:45:18.000 141541
31  2013-07-01 23:51:58.000 2013-07-01 23:54:33.000 141581
31  2013-07-02 13:03:17.000 2013-07-02 13:04:21.000 141621
158 2013-07-02 13:10:14.000 2013-07-02 13:11:09.000 141661
189 2013-07-02 13:13:48.000 2013-07-02 13:13:55.000 141701
202 2013-07-02 13:16:42.000 2013-07-02 13:16:42.000 141741
107 2013-07-02 13:19:31.000 2013-07-02 13:19:48.000 141781
31  2013-07-02 13:22:31.000 2013-07-02 13:24:44.000 141821
NULL    2013-03-21 18:59:22.000 2013-03-21 19:00:20.000 141861
NULL    2013-03-21 19:01:20.000 2013-03-21 19:01:30.000 141901
112 2013-03-21 19:03:29.000 2013-03-21 19:04:02.000 141941
159 2013-03-21 19:05:27.000 2013-03-21 19:06:31.000 141981
169 2013-03-21 19:07:25.000 2013-03-21 19:08:32.000 142021
NULL    2013-03-15 14:03:40.000 2013-03-15 14:04:14.000 142061
NULL    2013-03-15 14:04:41.000 2013-03-15 14:05:01.000 142101
NULL    2013-03-15 14:06:08.000 2013-03-15 14:07:10.000 142141
NULL    2013-03-15 14:07:47.000 2013-03-15 14:08:48.000 142181
65  2013-03-15 14:09:02.000 2013-03-15 14:09:17.000 142221
183 2013-05-21 17:25:14.000 2013-05-21 17:26:29.000 142261
NULL    2013-05-21 17:27:59.000 2013-05-21 17:28:35.000 142301
NULL    2013-05-21 17:31:42.000 2013-05-21 17:32:47.000 142341
166 2013-05-21 17:35:05.000 2013-05-21 17:36:01.000 142381
182 2013-05-21 17:37:38.000 2013-05-21 17:37:48.000 142421
166 2013-05-21 17:39:46.000 2013-05-21 17:40:21.000 142461
166 2013-04-24 22:13:50.000 2013-04-24 22:14:46.000 142501
65  2013-04-24 22:22:18.000 2013-04-24 22:22:21.000 142541
182 2013-04-24 22:25:54.000 2013-04-24 22:26:01.000 142581
116 2013-04-24 22:31:14.000 2013-04-24 22:31:23.000 142621
182 2013-04-24 22:35:55.000 2013-04-24 22:36:10.000 142661
31  2013-06-20 15:12:42.000 2013-06-20 15:13:39.000 142701
31  2013-06-20 15:20:08.000 2013-06-20 15:20:28.000 142741
31  2013-06-20 15:23:29.000 2013-06-20 15:23:45.000 142781
31  2013-06-20 15:26:39.000 2013-06-20 15:27:06.000 142821
31  2013-06-20 15:28:57.000 2013-06-20 15:29:44.000 142861
NULL    2013-04-24 22:37:50.000 2013-04-24 22:38:37.000 142901
NULL    2013-04-24 22:40:07.000 2013-04-24 22:41:41.000 142941
116 2013-04-24 22:45:09.000 2013-04-24 22:45:24.000 142981
187 2013-04-24 22:48:15.000 2013-04-24 22:48:24.000 143021
NULL    2013-04-24 22:54:57.000 2013-04-24 22:55:33.000 143061
NULL    2013-05-01 21:36:20.000 2013-05-01 21:37:44.000 143101
NULL    2013-05-01 21:39:56.000 2013-05-01 21:40:11.000 143141
NULL    2013-05-01 21:43:57.000 2013-05-01 21:46:34.000 143181
NULL    2013-05-01 21:49:29.000 2013-05-01 21:49:43.000 143221
NULL    2013-05-01 21:56:55.000 2013-05-01 21:57:26.000 143261
NULL    2013-05-01 22:03:51.000 2013-05-01 22:04:34.000 143301
85  2013-07-10 20:16:50.000 2013-07-10 20:16:52.000 143341
31  2013-07-10 20:19:46.000 2013-07-10 20:20:00.000 143381
31  2013-07-10 20:24:22.000 2013-07-10 20:25:03.000 143421
31  2013-07-10 20:26:23.000 2013-07-10 20:27:32.000 143461
31  2013-07-10 20:28:03.000 2013-07-10 20:28:51.000 143501
```

Comment: Can you post sample data from the `#ploto` table that causes your last query to produce the unexpected results?

Comment: See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (DDL), data to populate those tables, and the query attempt to retrieve the data against the tables as well as expected output. In other words a complete [mcve]. *You* providing these same artifacts *in your question* would go a long way into others being able to help you with your question.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that you're getting negative values. Wouldn't be surprised if this is something to do with the `isnull` function

Comment: It's part of the problem, yeah. But I get all nulls in #ploto if I don't include it. I would include sample results from #ploto but I suspect that #ploto's construction is erroneous so that would be counter-productive

Comment: format table ,https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really tried to understand your #ploto generation but couldn't. For example I didn't understand the join and what you are selecting and why would you want to get 0 when it is null (which means 1900/01/01). Also subtracting date times and casting to float is a hard to follow way of getting time as a day fraction.

From your description this is what I inferred:

```
WITH ploto
AS (SELECT AgentId,
           CallEnd,
           LEAD(CallStart) OVER (PARTITION BY agentId ORDER BY CallStart) AS nextCall
    FROM #thuranin)
SELECT AgentId,
       AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, CallEnd, nextCall)) AS average
FROM ploto
WHERE nextCall > CallEnd
      AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, callEnd, nextCall) < 6
GROUP BY AgentID;
```

With your sample data set output is (in seconds):

```
AgentId Average
NULL    287
31      326
65     1764
116     826
166     225
169     416
175     808
182     594
191    1569
```

And here is [SQLFiddle link.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9792a/2/0)

EDIT: Some explanation. You didn't specify version so I assumed at least MS SQL 2012. There are CallStarts (and CallEnd) that overlap with the previous (AgentId NULL). I removed them from check. Also arbitrarily assumed if there is more than 6 hours between a CallEnd and next CallStart then I should think employee's work has ended and she\he is gone home, that one shouldn't count.

Comment: Thank you! I was so stuck :P
I believe this gives the correct answer. Yeah, #ploto is uhh... I had a fun time figuring out how to calculate the time difference between each call. Not sure I did it right, but the fault is mine if so, good job