# TSQL help Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a flat table with the following attribs in a sql server 2012 db

`recno` int,
`part` varchar(50),
`ipart` varchar(50),
`remark` varchar(5)

table contains the following

[image]

**Sample Data**

```
declare @t table

(recno int,part varchar(50),ipart varchar(50),remark int)

insert into @t

values
(2 ,'0343432','9141212'   ,7),
(3 ,'73442'  ,'000832'    ,8),
(4 ,'911212' ,'28832'     ,9),
(5 ,'009832' ,'00988'    ,10),
(6 ,'57292'  ,'11234'    ,11),
(7 ,'9141212','0343432'   ,2),
(8 ,'000832' ,'73442'     ,3),
(9 ,'28832'  ,'911212'    ,4),
(10,'00988'  ,'009832'    ,5),
(11,'11234'  ,'57292'     ,6)
```

the data setup has a two way relationship.. i want to retain data with one way relation (row 2- 6) and remove row 7 - 11. any help/guidance will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (DDL), data to populate those tables, and the query attempt to retrieve the data against the tables as well as expected output. In other words a complete [mcve]. *You* providing these same artifacts *in your question* would go a long way into others being able to help you with your question. You could also use http://rextester.com/ for your DDL and data.

Comment: Please check the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) : `If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you.`. There's no table, just a screenshot. No relations either. It's hard to understand what you are asking, much less help solve the problem

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You don't actually seem to have asked for one, just stated you need help/guidance. What is it specifically you need help with? What is the **specific** problem you have, what have you tried to do to solve the problem and what issues/errors have you faced?

Comment: @AQuader what relation???? All recno values appear as remarks. Please don't make us *type* the values. Paste the *text* here

Comment: a two way relationship with what? You've missed lots of detail out of this. It's really not clear what you mean at all.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. ill try my best to elaborate the problem here. as per the image, if you take recno 2, part, ipart, remark data, they exists in recno 7, but in the opposite way. i want to use tsql to remove rows where such opposites exist. apology for if my wordings have been misleading. Thanks

Comment: *All* pairs appear twice. There's no "one-way" relation here. The only thing that would make sense is to ask for the first occurence of each `recno` or `part`, whichever is supposed to be the key for those rows

Comment: @AQuader all values exist twice.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that actually describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. *TSQL* is clear from the tag you added, as is *SQL Server*, *Microsoft* is meaningless because SQL Server has always been a MS product, and *help* is clear because you're posting here. All of that means that your current title contains no useful information. Your title should be descriptive enough to be of use to a future user here who is scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS comments obvious reveals there is missing some cruicial information from you. However, with the basic knowledge we have (row 2-6) - Will this work for you?

```
declare @table table

(recno int,part varchar(50),ipart varchar(50),remark int)

insert into @table 

values
(2 ,'0343432','9141212' ,7),
(3 ,'73442' ,'000832'   ,8),
(4 ,'911212'    ,'28832'    ,9),
(5 ,'009832'    ,'00988'    ,10),
(6 ,'57292' ,'11234'    ,11),
(7 ,'9141212','0343432' ,2),
(8 ,'000832'    ,'73442'    ,3),
(9 ,'28832' ,'911212'   ,4),
(10,'00988' ,'009832'   ,5),
(11,'11234' ,'57292'    ,6)

select a.recno,a.part,a.ipart,a.remark from @table a
inner join @table b on a.part = b.ipart

where a.remark > b.remark
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your design is bad, you could remove those rows:

```
delete from myTable 
where try_convert(int, remark) > 0 and try_convert(int, remark) < recno;
```

[Link to SQLFiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e33de/1)

Note: Your image had the remark as varchar. You don't need conversion when it is already int:

```
delete from myTable 
where remark > 0 and remark < recno;
```