# Determining consecutive and independent PTO days

Tags: sql, presto

Based on feedback, I am restructuring my question.

I am working with SQL on a Presto database.

My objective is to report on employees that take consecutive days of PTO or Sick Time since the beginning of 2018. My desired output would have the individual islands of time taken by employee with the start and end dates, along the lines of:

[image]

The main table I am using is d_employee_time_off

[image]

There are only two time_off_type_name: PTO and Sick Leave.

The ds is a datestamp and I use the latest ds (usually the current date)

I have access to a date table named d_date

[image]

I can join the tables on d_employee_time_off.time_off_date = d_date.full_date

I hope that I have structured this question in a fashion that is understandable.

Comment: @KenWhite This is an "islands" requirement, not satisfied by regular min() max() and group by.

Comment: Instead of showing us some query output (that isn't correct), can you supply just the source data as a sample please. It is useful to also see the query you have tried as well.

Comment: @Used_By_Already the source data is literally just the employee_id, type (which is just PTO or Sick Leave), date, and time_off_in_days (which is always 1). I joined to a date table to get the day names and  used a lead and lag function to get the previous and future date.

Your identification of this issue being an 'islands' requirement has led me to some good reading so I will hammer on this and update as I attempt to find a solution

Comment: See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (DDL), data to populate those tables, and the query attempt to retrieve the data against the tables as well as expected output. In other words a complete [mcve]. *You* providing these same artifacts *in your question* would go a long way into others being able to help you with your question. You could also use http://rextester.com/ for your DDL and data.

Comment: Thank you @Igor. I will look at that question and the other links you provided.

Comment: source also has `t.ds = '<LATEST_DS:d_employee_time_off>'` and it probably also has a primary key. Please provide samples from the source table (NOT the output of a failed query). It may seem redundant to you, but you have access to the source data... we don't. Please include the primary key in your sample.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. You mention having access to a calendar table for day of week. Does that table include weekends? Can you supply a sample of this table too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the need here is to join the day off material to a calendar table.

In the example solution below I am generating this "on the fly" but I think you do have your own solution for this. Also in my example I have used the string 'Monday' and moved backward from that (or, you could use 'Friday' and move forward). I'm, not keen on language dependent solutions but as I'm not a Presto user wasn't able to test anything on Presto. So the example below uses some of your own logic, but using SQL Server syntax which I trust you can translate to Presto:

Query:

```
;WITH
Digits AS (
          SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL
          SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL  
          SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
          SELECT 9
          )
, cal AS (
          SELECT 
                 ca.number
               , dateadd(day,ca.number,'20180101') as cal_date
               , datename(weekday,dateadd(day,ca.number,'20180101')) weekday
          FROM Digits [1s]
          CROSS JOIN Digits [10s]
          CROSS JOIN Digits [100s] /* add more like this as needed */
          cross apply (
              SELECT 
                      [1s].digit 
                    + [10s].digit * 10
                    + [100s].digit * 100  /* add more like this as needed */
                    AS number
              ) ca
          )
, time_off AS (
        select
            *
        from cal
        inner join mytable t on (cal.cal_date = t.time_off_date and cal.weekday <> 'Monday') 
                             or (cal.cal_date between dateadd(day,-2,t.time_off_date) 
                                  and t.time_off_date and datename(weekday,t.time_off_date) = 'Monday')
        )
, starting_points AS (
        SELECT
            employee_id,
            cal_date,
            dense_rank() OVER(partition by employee_id
                ORDER BY
                    time_off_date
            ) AS rownum
        FROM
            time_off A
        WHERE
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    time_off B
                WHERE
                    B.employee_id = A.employee_id
                    AND B.cal_date = DATEADD(day, -1, A.cal_date)
            )
    )
, ending_points AS (
        SELECT
            employee_id,
            cal_date,
            dense_rank() OVER(partition by employee_id
                ORDER BY
                    time_off_date
            ) AS rownum
        FROM
            time_off A
        WHERE
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    time_off B
                WHERE
                    B.employee_id = A.employee_id
                    AND B.cal_date = DATEADD(day, 1, A.cal_date)
            )
    )
SELECT
    S.employee_id,
    S.cal_date AS start_range,
    E.cal_date AS end_range
FROM
    starting_points S
JOIN
    ending_points E
    ON E.employee_id = S.employee_id
    AND E.rownum = S.rownum
order by employee_id
    , start_range
```

Result:

```
    employee_id start_range end_range
1   200035      02.01.2018  02.01.2018 
2   200035      20.04.2018  27.04.2018 
3   200037      27.01.2018  29.01.2018 
4   200037      31.03.2018  02.04.2018
```

see: http://rextester.com/MISZ50793

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ID INT NOT NULL
  ,employee_id      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,type             VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,time_off_date         DATE  NOT NULL
  ,time_off_in_days INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,employee_id,type,time_off_date,time_off_in_days) VALUES (1,200035,'PTO','2018-01-02',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,employee_id,type,time_off_date,time_off_in_days) VALUES (2,200035,'PTO','2018-04-20',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,employee_id,type,time_off_date,time_off_in_days) VALUES (3,200035,'PTO','2018-04-23',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,employee_id,type,time_off_date,time_off_in_days) VALUES (4,200035,'PTO','2018-04-24',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,employee_id,type,time_off_date,time_off_in_days) VALUES (5,200035,'PTO','2018-04-25',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,employee_id,type,time_off_date,time_off_in_days) VALUES (6,200035,'PTO','2018-04-26',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,employee_id,type,time_off_date,time_off_in_days) VALUES (7,200035,'PTO','2018-04-27',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,employee_id,type,time_off_date,time_off_in_days) VALUES (8,200037,'PTO','2018-01-29',1);
INSERT INTO mytable(id,employee_id,type,time_off_date,time_off_in_days) VALUES (9,200037,'PTO','2018-04-02',1);
```

Comment: Hopefully you can now see how necessary it is to provide sample data (not query results), and also how useful it would have been to have some of your calendar table available to use. Providing samples would have enabled a much faster reply to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a noob and am still learning so please forgive my poor question structuring (I believe I was restructuring my question as you were providing an answer).

I really appreciate your help and I promise to work to get better.

Comment: Not at all, your question is far from poor, just pointing out possible improvement - which, also, would ultimately be to your advantage. However don't use images of data, that's not very friendly to use as it requires someone to transcribe it. Simple text tables are far better. Image if my answer was an image of a query :). Not sure why you removed your query either, that should have stayed in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I will re-edit the question as I want to be able to formulate good questions. Thank you again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: :) ok, but I would reserve your efforts to reading these https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and/or  
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query then put that into practice for your next questions.