# Grouping causing more rows than required

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to do a sum of data based on  a code but the sum is working but still individual lines are being showing.

```
SELECT  
    nom.AccntntCod, nom.AcctName, cc.PrcCode, cc.PrcName,
    SUM(line.Credit) AS CreditTotal,
    SUM(line.Debit) AS DebitTotal  
FROM 
    OJDT head
LEFT JOIN  
    JDT1 line ON head.TransId = line.TransId
LEFT JOIN 
    OACT nom ON line.Account = nom.AcctCode
LEFT JOIN 
    OPRC cc ON line.ProfitCode = cc.PrcCode
WHERE 
    DimCode IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    PrcCode, CC.DimCode, nom.AccntntCod, nom.AcctName, cc.PrcCode, cc.PrcName
```

As you see I am trying to group by Prc Code but I am still getting some duplication here as I only want one lne of HS07 with a combined credit total and debit total amount any ideas help is most welcome.

[image]

Comment: See this [*previous question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (**DDL**), insert **data** to populate those tables, and the **query** attempt to retrieve the data against the tables as well as **expected output**. In other words a complete [mcve]. *You* providing these same artifacts *in your question* would go a long way into others being able to help you with your question. You could also use http://rextester.com/ for your DDL and data.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you SELECT, except those columns who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one row per `PrcCode`, then remove the account information from the query:

```
SELECT cc.PrcCode, cc.PrcName, sum(line.Credit) AS CreditTotal, 
      sum(line.Debit) as DebitTotal 
FROM OJDT head LEFT JOIN
     JDT1 line
     on head.TransId = line.TransId LEFT JOIN
     OACT nom
     on line.Account = nom.AcctCode LEFT JOIN
     OPRC cc
     ON line.ProfitCode = cc.PrcCode
WHERE DimCode IS NOT NULL  -- what table is this in?  You should qualify it
group by cc.PrcCode, cc.PrcName;
```

Comment: I need the account code to show im afriad would their be anyway of allowing that gordon

Comment: @david . . . According to the question:  "I am trying to group by Prc Code but I am still getting some duplication here as I only want one lne of HS07 with a combined credit total and debit total ".  That sounds like you do not want the account code.