# Give reasons as to why my AND clause returns an empty string in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL and it seems not to be the same as tradition coding. Anyways, I am trying to figure out why my results end up empty but only with the first AND statement. If I remove this statement, the code works. The syntax seems correct. What I am trying to do is match channel names with 'P' and 'HDP' at the end of the columns and not match channel numbers. Maybe I am wrong on the syntax. Any help on this matter would be appreciated. Also, I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

How the results should look:

[image]

```
SELECT a.ChannelNumber AS "Standard Channel",
       a.DisplayName AS "Standard Name",
       b.ChannelNumber AS "HD Channel",
       b.DisplayName AS "HD Name"               
FROM   CHANNEL a CROSS JOIN CHANNEL b
WHERE  b.ChannelNumber <> a.ChannelNumber
AND    b.DisplayName = a.DisplayName        /*this is what is giving me problems*/
AND    RIGHT(b.DisplayName, 3) LIKE '%HDP' 
AND    RIGHT(a.DisplayName, 1) LIKE '%P';
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, please read **[this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)** and try to edit your question. A beside note don't ever use images, instead post the sample data and expected results as formatted text. Thank you :)

Comment: `b.DisplayName = a.DisplayName` <= that in the where clause will return only records where there is an exact match between these 2 fields. It makes perfect sense that this would result in an empty result set if you included this considering the other filters you have.

Comment: To expand on @Igor it's possible for both `a.DisplayName` and `b.DisplayName` to satisfy all 3 statements (if they are both equal to `ABCHDP` they will be equal, `a` will end in 'P' and `b` will and in `HDP`) but given the data you've provided it's not going to happen

Comment: What is confusing about this all is that I used the exact same code in another problem, minus the CROSS JOIN and the results returned correct. I am noticing that the there is some conflict between the two. If I use only the = then the results work. Once I add in the <> then I am back to square one

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you tried to run the query without the `b.DisplayName = a.DisplayName` and check whether there's a row where `Standard Name` = `HD Name`???  If not, then there's your problem.

Comment: Yes, `b.DisplayName = a.DisplayName` does come back correct. I think `b.DisplayName = a.DisplayName` and `b.ChannelNumber <> a.ChannelNumber` are conflicting but as to how, am I lost.

Comment: See this [*previous question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (**DDL**), insert **data** to populate those tables, and the **query** attempt to retrieve the data against the tables as well as **expected output**. In other words a complete [mcve]. *You* providing these same artifacts *in your question* would go a long way into others being able to help you with your question. You could also use http://rextester.com/ for your DDL and data.

Comment: According to the output picture, the DisplayName is spelled differently between the two tables- yet the query is coded that they be the equal (spelled the same, etc.).  Putting a different alias in the SELECT for the two DisplayNames (calling one "Standard Name" and the other "HD Name" is irrelevant to the comparison occurring in the WHERE.

Comment: Are you under the impression that `AETVP=AETVHDP` in SQL?   It doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question,

> "Give reasons as to why my AND clause returns an empty string in SQL"

- it's because you've declared a.DisplayName = b.DisplayName in the WHERE.  And that can't be the case according to the picture of the output you've linked to because the Display names are spelled differently.

The only difference between standard and HD tables is HD tables end with "HDP".  Standard tables never end with "HDP", though they do end with a "P".

In the absence of sample data, I've included the most basic example I could think of using a temp table.

```
DECLARE @CHANNEL TABLE(ChannelNumber int, DisplayName varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @CHANNEL VALUES
 (3, 'ABCP'), (25, 'ABCHDP')

SELECT a.ChannelNumber AS "Standard Channel",
       a.DisplayName AS "Standard Name",
       b.ChannelNumber AS "HD Channel",
       b.DisplayName AS "HD Name"  
  FROM @CHANNEL a CROSS JOIN @CHANNEL b
 WHERE LEFT(a.DisplayName, LEN(a.DisplayName) - 1) + 'HDP' = b.DisplayName
   AND a.DisplayName NOT LIKE '%HDP'
   AND b.DisplayName LIKE '%HDP'
   AND a.ChannelNumber <> b.ChannelNumber
```

Produces output:

```
Standard Channel    Standard Name   HD Channel  HD Name
               3    ABCP            25          ABCHDP
```

The algorithm identifies standard channels (`NOT LIKE '%HDP'`) and HD channels (`LIKE '%HDP'`) on the left and right sides of the CROSS JOIN.

Notice in your code you put: `AND    RIGHT(b.DisplayName, 3) LIKE '%HDP'`... it is unnecessary to specify the `RIGHT` function with a length of chars- when you indicate the end of the string using `LIKE '%HDP'`.

`LEFT(a.DisplayName, LEN(a.DisplayName) - 1) + 'HDP'` cuts off the last char of the Standard Channel's DisplayName (which is always a 'P' by it's naming convention) and concatenates 'HDP' at the end of the result.  This is compared to the format for HD channels which always end with 'HDP'.

When the conditions match you get a row of data.

Looking at the filtering conditions- you can see that a.DisplayName ***can never equal*** b.DisplayName

Comment: Thank you for breaking this problem down to me in much detail. Like I said, SQL is a bit confusing out the gate but you broke my code down and then did a  great job explaining why I was having trouble. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you want things like `AETVP` and `AETVHDP` to be "equal". This doesn't seem like a use case for a `Cross Join`. You can break this down with a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

First you'll define your HD channels, then your Standard Channels. In each of those blocks you can get the core part of the channel's name (the part without the `P` or `HDP`). Then join those together on the CoreName. This will enable us to join `AETV` to `AETV`

```
WITH HdChannels
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,CoreName = left(DisplayName, len(DisplayName) - len('HDP'))
    FROM Channel
    WHERE displayName LIKE '%HDP'
    )
    ,StdChannels
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,CoreName = left(DisplayName, len(DisplayName) - len('P'))
    FROM Channel
    WHERE displayName LIKE '%P'
        AND displayName NOT LIKE '%HDP'
    )
SELECT std.ChannelNumber AS [Standard Channel]
    ,std.DisplayName AS [Standard Name]
    ,hd.ChannelNumber AS [HD Channel]
    ,hd.DisplayName AS [HD Name]
FROM HdChannels hd
INNER JOIN StdChannels std ON std.CoreName = hd.CoreName
```

Comment: This is a great way to do this, unfortunately I am required to use CROSS JOIN on this. Thank you though!

Comment: What does being required to use Cross Join mean? Why the restriction?

Comment: The teacher requires this. I went to my tutoring center and they were no help so I was forced to reach out to get more insight on the matter.

Comment: If you do some research on what the uses of `Cross join` are you'll see that it is for repeating every row of `a` with every row of `b`. Because you are restricting the output with a where clause and your intention is to match 1 standard def channel with it's corresponding HD channel an `Inner Join` is the proper style of join to use here. You can write `Cross` instead of `Inner` (then move the `On` clause to a `Where` because cross join don't have join conditions) and it will produce the same output.

Comment: The thing that I'm really pointing out with this answer is that you want to join on the core part of the display name not the display name in it's entirety (which will never be equal)

Comment: @user10466320 the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) article on Joins is a quick read and has pictures which hopefully explain the gist of why the operation occurring here is an Inner Join.

Comment: I understand `CROSS JOIN` to some extent. I didn't make sense that he wants use to use it when we are using only the same table. I want to use `Inner Join` but he has yet to email me back. This is his remark in the assignment _Note: There are ways to do this that don''t require a CROSS JOIN, but use a CROSS
JOIN anyway._   Thank you for all your help

Comment: @user10466320 I think what I've written is correct but if you must use a Cross Join I think you see how to modify this answer to do that.

Comment: I 100% think your answer is correct as well. Also, I believe I have narrowed it down. Thank you again for your help!