# I don't know how to correct this sql exercises

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using ORACLE, and this queries are done in the HR schema. My problem is that this queries are not perfect, and I'm lost and don't know how to continue. (Please don't be rude like do your homework because I only ask when I've tried stuff). Btw, the statements are in spanish but I translated them.

1. Nombre de empleado y nombre de departamento de los empleados que superan la media de sueldo del departamento al que pertenecen.
ENGLISH: Employee name and department name of the employees that exceed the salary average of the department to which they belong.

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_name
    from employees e
    INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
    where salary > (select avg(salary)
                        from employees
                        where department_id = department_id);
```

5. Empleados que, en cada departamento, tienen el sueldo máximo.
   ENGLISH: Employees who, in each department, have the maximum salary

```
select e.employee_id
    from employees e
    INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
    where salary = (select hire_date
                        from employees
                        where employee_id = 107);
```

8. Empleados que trabajen en departamentos en los que nadie cobre comisiones.
   ENGLISH: Employees who work in departments where no one charges commissions

```
select e.employee_id
    from employees e
    INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
    where commission_pct = (select sum(commission_pct)
                                from employees
                                group by department_id
                                having sum(commission_pct) = 0);
```

10. Para cada departamento que tenga 3 o más trabajadores, calcular el total de salarios, el total de comisiones y el
    número de trabajadores. Mostrar el nombre del departamento y las 3 cantidades.
    ENGLISH: For each department that has 3 or more workers, calculate the total wages, the total of commissions and the
    number of workers. Show the name of the department and the 3 quantities

```
select sum(e.salary), sum(e.commission_pct), count(e.employee_id), d.department_name
    from employees e
    INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
    where count(e.employee_id) >= 3;
```

Comment: First: 1 question per [so] question, do not lump all your homework questions into 1 question here. Second: How are we supposed to know what is wrong in your query (assuming now you asked 1 question)?

Comment: ^-- (continued) See this [*previous question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (**DDL**), insert **data** to populate those tables, and the **query** attempt to retrieve the data against the tables as well as **expected output**. In other words a complete [mcve]. *You* providing these same artifacts *in your question* would go a long way into others being able to help you with your question. You could also use http://rextester.com/ for your DDL and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close in most cases.

---

As of 1: You should use table aliases, always. If you do not, the result is *unpredictable* and - most probably - wrong. Should be:

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name, d.department_name
    from employees e
    INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
    where e.salary > (select avg(e1.salary)
                        from employees e1
                        where e1.department_id = d.department_id);  --> aliases, especially here!
```

---

As of 5: your query doesn't make sense; how about this?

```
select d.department_name, e.employee_id
from employees e INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
where e.salary = (select max(e1.salary) 
                  from employees e1
                  where e1.department_id = d.department_id);
```

---

As of 8:

```
select e.employee_id, d.department_name
    from employees e
    INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
where e.department_id in (select e1.department_id
                          from employees e1
                          group by e1.department_id
                          having sum(commission_pct) is null;
```

---

As of 10:

```
select sum(e.salary), sum(e.commission_pct), count(e.employee_id), d.department_name
    from employees e
    INNER JOIN departments d ON e.department_id = d.department_id
    group by d.department_name
    having count(*) >= 3;
```