# Finding Active Clients By Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble writing a recursive function that would count the number of active clients on any given day.

Say I have a table like this:

| Client | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-Jan-22 |  |
| 2 | 1-Jan-22 | 3-Jan-22 |
| 3 | 3-Jan-22 |  |
| 4 | 4-Jan-22 | 5-Jan-22 |
| 5 | 4-Jan-22 | 6-Jan-22 |
| 6 | 7-Jan-22 | 9-Jan-22 |

I want to return a table that would look like this:

| Date | NumActive |
| --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-22 | 2 |
| 2-Jan-22 | 2 |
| 3-Jan-22 | 3 |
| 4-Jan-22 | 4 |
| 5-Jan-22 | 4 |
| 6-Jan-22 | 3 |
| 7-Jan-22 | 3 |
| 8-Jan-22 | 3 |
| 9-Jan-22 | 4 |

Is there a way to do this? Ideally, I'd have a fixed start date and go to today's date.

Some pieces I have tried:

### Creating a recursive date table

Truncated to Feb 1, 2022 for simplicity:

```
WITH DateDiffs AS (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2022-02-02', GETDATE()) AS NumDays
)

, Numbers(Numbers) AS (
    SELECT MAX(NumDays) FROM DateDiffs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Numbers-1 FROM Numbers WHERE Numbers > 0 
    ) 

, Dates AS (
    SELECT
        Numbers
        , DATEADD(DAY, -Numbers, CAST(GETDATE() -1 AS DATE)) AS [Date]
    FROM Numbers
)
```

I would like to be able to loop over the dates in that table, such as by modifying the query below for each date, such as by @loopdate. Then UNION ALL it to a larger final query.
I'm now stuck as to how I can run the query to count the number of active users:

```sql
SELECT
COUNT(Client)
FROM clients
WHERE [Start Date] >= @loopdate AND ([End Date] <= @loopdate OR [End Date] IS NULL)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I have added what I've done so far.

Comment: See this [*previous question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (**DDL**), insert **data** to populate those tables, and the **query** attempt to retrieve the data against the tables as well as **expected output**. In other words a complete [mcve]. Providing these same artifacts *in your question* would go a long way into others being able to help you with your question. You could also use http://rextester.com/ for your DDL and data.

Comment: Having a date/calendar table would go a long way and I think it's worth creating one. That is a table that has a column containing every date. With that you can do very simple logic like `SELECT calendartable.date, count(*) FROM calendartable LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable ON calendartable.date BETWEEN yourtable.startdate and yourtable.enddate WHERE calendartable.date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' and '2022-02-28 GROUP BY calendartable.date'` (for example).

Comment: Your sample data should be 3, not 4 for the last row I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything recursive in this particular case, you need as a minimum a list of dates in the range you want to report on, ideally a permanent *calendar table*.

for purposes of demonstration you can create something on the fly, and use it like so, with the list of dates something you *outer join* to:

```
with dates as (
    select top(9) 
      Convert(date,DateAdd(day, -1 + Row_Number() over(order by (select null)), '20220101')) dt
    from master.dbo.spt_values
)

select d.dt [Date], c.NumActive
from dates d
outer apply (
  select Count(*) NumActive
  from t
  where d.dt >= t.StartDate and (d.dt <= t.EndDate or t.EndDate is null)
)c
```

See this [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75f96a393a7c8e4a42fa852dfd78fcf7)

Comment: Edit: I was able to get this working. Thank you SO much!! I've been at this for hours. I unfortunately can't publicly upvote, but please know I'm very grateful!

Comment: @leviosa Yes you can try master.sys.columns [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=429e2dd832ad76b1ac144408419bbcb6)- but it should not be a problem, see the demo fiddle - What version of SQL Server are you using?