# SQL - Returning max count, after breaking down a day into hourly rows

Tags: sql, datetime, count, max

I need to write a SQL query that helps return the highest count in a given hourly range. The problem is that in my table, it just logs orders as they come and doesn’t have a unique identifier that separates hours from hours.

So basically, I need to find the highest number of orders (on any given hour), from 7/08/2022, - 7/15/2022, have a table that does not distinguish distinct hour sets, and logs orders as they come.

I have tried to use a query that combines MAX(), COUNT(), and DATETIME(), but to no avail.

Can I please receive some help?

Comment: See this [*previous question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (**DDL**), insert **data** to populate those tables, and the **query** attempt to retrieve the data against the tables as well as **expected output**. In other words a complete [mcve]. *You* providing these same artifacts *in your question* would go a long way into others being able to help you with your question. You could also use http://rextester.com/ for your DDL and data.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I've had to tackle this kind of measurement in the past..
Here's what I did for 15 minute intervals:

My datetime column is named datreg in my database log area.

```
cast(round(floor(cast(datreg as float(53))*24*4)/(24*4),5) as smalldatetime
```

I times by 4 in this formula, to get 4 intervals inside my 24 hour period..
 For you it would look like this to get just hourly intervals:

```
cast(round(floor(cast(datreg as float(53))*24)/(24),5) as smalldatetime
```

This is a little piece of magic when it comes to dashboards and reports.