# Evaluating datetime into timewindows

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

Im trying to establish for any given datetime a tag that is purely dependent on the time part.
However because the time part is cyclic I cant make it work with simple greater lower than conditions.
I tried a lot of casting and shift one time to 24hour mark to kinda break the cycle However it just gets more and more complicated and still doesnt work.

Im using SQL-Server, here is the situation:

```
DECLARE @tagtable TABLE (tag varchar(10),[start] time,[end] time);
DECLARE @datetimestable TABLE ([timestamp] datetime)

Insert Into @tagtable (tag, [start], [end])
values ('tag1','04:00:00.0000000','11:59:59.9999999'),
('tag2','12:00:00.0000000','19:59:59.9999999'),
('tag3','20:00:00.0000000','03:59:59.9999999');

Insert Into @datetimestable ([timestamp])
values ('2022-07-24T23:05:23.120'),
('2022-07-27T13:24:40.650'),
('2022-07-26T09:00:00.000');
```

tagtable:

| tag | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tag1 | 04:00:00.0000000 | 11:59:59.9999999 |
| tag2 | 12:00:00.0000000 | 19:59:59.9999999 |
| tag3 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 03:59:59.9999999 |

for given datetimes e.g. `2022-07-24 23:05:23.120`, `2022-07-27 13:24:40.650`, `2022-07-26 09:00:00.000`

the desired result would be:

| date | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-25 | tag3 |
| 2022-07-27 | tag2 |
| 2022-07-26 | tag1 |

As I wrote i tried to twist this with casts and adding and datediffs

```
SELECT 
If(Datepart(Hour, a.[datetime]) > 19, 
   Cast(Dateadd(Day,1,a.[datetime]) as Date), 
   Cast(a.[datetime] as Date)
  ) as [date], 
b.[tag]
FROM @datetimestable a
INNER JOIN @tagtable b 
   ON SomethingWith(a.[datetime]) 
      between SomethingWith(b.[start]) and SomethingWith(b.[end])
```

Comment: Thank you for including tables and a query. See also this [*previous question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (**DDL**), insert **data** to populate those tables. In other words a complete [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand the question. The time itself is a tag that is purely dependent on the time. I suspect it will be easier to write a query if you can first articulate what it is that you're trying to actually do. The title says _timezone_ but that is not mentioned again.

Comment: You could do it if you did not embed an assumption in your tag schema. Effectively tag3 has two "periods". One that starts at 20:00 and ends at 23:59 and one that starts at 00:00 and ends at 03:59. If you had those rows, your logic becomes much simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the DDL and sample input. I changed your DDL to use variables for tables. That way anyone can copy/paste it into a Sql script and run it multiple times without having to create/drop tables. This will make it easier to help you find an answer for your question.

Comment: yeah well my solutions were becoming the real complicated bit. Maybe i should call it timewindow in stead of timezones? It is the time that sits between tagtable.start and tagtable.end. I want it to be a more general tag than the exact time to enable grouping over larger periods

Comment: Could you explain why the record with `2022-07-24T23:05:23.120` as the timestamp shows as `2022-07-25` in the expected result?

Comment: `2022-07-24T23:05:23.120` is shown as `2022-07-25`, because its supposed to count towards the next day. Its just definition, but since i want only the date part, you have to make a choice, either way you need to put additional logic to the select just as i did in my query example. It doesnt really matter if its 24 or 25, the point is that the whole tag count towards one day not two different days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only tricky bit here is that your tag time ranges can go over midnight, so you need to check that your time is either between start and end, or if it spans midnight its between `start` and 23:59:59 or between 00:00:00 and `end`.

The only other piece is splitting your `timestamp` column into date and time using a CTE, to save having to repeat the cast.

```
;WITH splitTimes AS
(
    SELECT CAST(timestamp AS DATE) as D,
     CAST(timestamp AS TIME) AS T
    FROM @datetimestable
)
SELECT 
DATEADD(
   day,
   CASE WHEN b.[end]<b.start THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
   a.D) as timestamp,
b.[tag]
FROM [splitTimes] a
INNER JOIN @tagtable b 
   ON a.T between b.[start] and b.[end]
   OR (b.[end]<b.start AND (a.T BETWEEN b.[start] AND '23:59:59.99999'
   OR a.T BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND b.[end]))
```

Live example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=506aef05b5a761afaf1f67a6d729446c

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am looking at this to simple, but,
can't you just take the first tag with an hour greater then your hour in table datetimestable.
With an order by desc it should always give you the correct tag.
**This will work well as long as you have no gaps in your tagtable**

```
select case when datepart(hour, tag.tagStart) > 19 then dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, dt.timestamp))
            else convert(date, dt.timestamp)
       end as [date],
       tag.tag
from   datetimestable dt 
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       tt.tag,
                       tt.tagStart
                from   tagtable tt
                where  datepart(Hour, dt.timestamp) > datepart(hour, tt.tagStart)
                order by tt.tagStart desc
             ) tag
```

It returns the correct result in [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=34c40ee2da04f698cd4de91dc91d99d0)

The result is

| date | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-25 | tag3 |
| 2022-07-27 | tag2 |
| 2022-07-26 | tag1 |

**EDIT**

**If it is possible that there are gaps in the table,**

then I think the most easy and solid solution would be to split that row that passes midnight into 2 rows, and then your query can be very simple
See [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5e578d798b9d1e190475cc6c4369d74)

```
select case when datepart(hour, tag.tagStart) > 19 then dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, dt.timestamp))
            else convert(date, dt.timestamp)
       end as [date],
       tag.tag
from   datetimestable dt 
  outer apply ( select tt.tag,
                       tt.tagStart
                from   tagtable tt
                where  datepart(Hour, dt.timestamp) >= datepart(hour, tt.tagStart)
                and    datepart(Hour, dt.timestamp) <= datepart(hour, tt.tagEnd)
             ) tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a completely different approach that defines the intervals in terms of starts and durations rather than starts and ends.

This allows the creation of tags that can span multiple days, which might seem like an odd capability to have here, but there might be a use for it if we add some more conditions down the line. For example, say we want to be able say "anything from 6pm friday to 9am monday gets the 'out of hours' tag". Then we could add a day of week predicate to the tag definition, and still use the duration-based interval.

I have defined the duration granularity in terms of hours, but of course this can easily be changed

```sql
create table #tags
(
   tag varchar(10),
   startTimeInclusive time,
   durationHours int
);

insert   #tags
values   ('tag1','04:00:00', 8),
         ('tag2','12:00:00', 8),
         ('tag3','20:00:00', 8);

create table #dateTimes (dt datetime)

insert   #dateTimes
values   ('2022-07-24T23:05:23.120'),
         ('2022-07-27T13:24:40.650'),
         ('2022-07-26T09:00:00.000');

select   dt.dt,
         t.tag
from     #datetimes     dt
join     #tags          t  on cast(dt.dt as time) >= t.startTimeInclusive
                              and dt.dt < dateadd
                              (
                                 hour,
                                 t.durationHours,
                                 cast(cast(dt.dt as date) as datetime) -- strip the time from dt
                                 + cast(t.startTimeInclusive as datetime) -- add back the time from t
                              );
```