# How can I return the Maximum Letters for a particular location using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

| TicketNumber | FullName | Type | ActionTaken | CPZName | DateReceived | DateResponded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A306250992 | Robson de Souza | letter | Re-issue Notice | Lannisport | 06/09/2022 | 2022/10/06 10:35:48 |
| A306180194 | Rivaldo Vitor Borba Ferreira | email | Re-issue Notice | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/01/06 12:07:05 |
| A306054145 | Ronaldo de Assis Moreira | User Note | Hold For 14 Days | Jurassic Park | 06/09/2022 | 2022/11/06 20:53:16 |
| A307716063 | Wayne Mark Rooney | email | Re-Offer Discount | Atlantis | NULL | 2022/08/06 10:30:04 |
| A304495365 | Joseph John Cole | email | Notice Of Rejection With Discount | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/01/06 08:12:54 |
| A306138799 | Rivaldo Vitor Borba Ferreira | letter | No reply | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/06/06 12:15:34 |
| A306119841 | Lionel Andrés Messi | User Note | Notice Of Rejection With Discount | Lannisport | 06/10/2022 | 2022/10/06 13:35:12 |
| A30621503A | Steven George Gerrard | letter | No Action | Lannisport | 06/01/2022 | 2022/10/06 15:19:54 |
| A307480160 | Samuel Eto'o Fils | User Note | Re-Issue NTO HHT | Lilliput | 06/06/2022 | 2022/07/06 12:25:19 |
| A306176776 | Carlos Alberto Tevez | email | No Action | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/06/06 09:21:09 |
| A304337761 | Rivaldo Vitor Borba Ferreira | letter | Cancel | Hogwarts | 06/10/2022 | 2022/10/06 12:44:04 |
| A306207610 | Joseph John Cole | email | Re-issue Notice | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/01/06 13:08:41 |
| A304499402 | Vincent Jean Mpoy Kompany | letter | Cancel | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/06/06 10:21:00 |
| A306102350 | Leroy Aziz Sané | letter | Cancel | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/01/06 10:33:52 |
| A30763960A | Gareth Frank Bale | letter | Hold For 14 Days | Crownlands | 06/02/2022 | 2022/09/06 14:03:03 |
| A306160018 | Rivaldo Vitor Borba Ferreira | letter | Notice Of Rejection With Discount | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/01/06 14:20:43 |
| A307657951 | Ronaldo Luís Nazário de Lima | letter | Hold For 14 Days | Crownlands | 06/02/2022 | 2022/10/06 13:27:41 |
| A307678601 | Luís Carlos Almeida de Cunha | email | Hold For 14 Days | Atlantis | NULL | 2022/08/06 10:43:07 |
| A306235387 | Steven George Gerrard | letter | Notice Of Rejection With Discount | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/10/06 12:55:06 |
| A307499726 | Steven George Gerrard | letter | Re-Issue NTO HHT | Hogwarts | 06/08/2022 | 2022/09/06 12:59:52 |
| A30614027A | Lionel Andrés Messi | email | No Action | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/09/06 11:09:33 |
| A306125072 | Dimitar Ivanov Berbatov | letter | Re-issue Notice | Asgard | NULL | 2022/06/06 17:09:53 |
| A307699033 | José María Gutiérrez Hernández | email | No Action | Atlantis | NULL | 2022/08/06 11:53:07 |
| A30772307A | Leroy Aziz Sané | email | Hold For 14 Days | Bankside | 06/05/2022 | 2022/10/06 16:23:47 |
| A306071803 | Ronaldo de Assis Moreira | User Note | Hold For 14 Days | Jurassic Park | 06/11/2022 | 2022/11/06 21:30:50 |
| A306238716 | Joseph John Cole | email | Notice Of Rejection With Discount | Lannisport | NULL | 2022/10/06 10:22:14 |
| A307703072 | Diego Armando Maradona | email | Hold For 14 Days | Jurassic Park | 06/07/2022 | 2022/10/06 12:01:30 |
| A307704020 | Luís Carlos Almeida de Cunha | email | No reply | Hogsmeade | NULL | 2022/01/06 09:57:04 |
| A307672660 | Ronaldo Luís Nazário de Lima | email | Hold For 14 Days | Crownlands | 06/03/2022 | 2022/09/06 15:34:43 |

I have the following SQL code which isn't working:

```
SELECT MAX(SUM(case when Type = 'email' then 1 else 0 end)) AS 'MaxEmails'
FROM Tickets AS T
INNER JOIN Officers AS O
  ON T.OfficerID = O.OfficerID
INNER JOIN Types AS Ty
  ON T.TypeID = Ty.TypeID
INNER JOIN Actions AS A
  ON T.ActionID = A.ActionID
INNER JOIN ControlledParkingZones AS C
  ON T.CPZCode = C.CPZCode;
```

I am trying to return the name of the CPZName with the Maximum number of Emails.

I'd like the results to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: you need to use a GROUP BY statement to compute the sum over each CPZName

Comment: What is your DBMS product? SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I am using SQL Server and SSMS

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. I.e. a [mcve]

Comment: I tried to paste the table but it looks like it will take a really long time to do the formatting. I copied it on SSMS and pasted it onto the question box, converted it to code but the entire table became a mess. How do you normally do it?

Comment: See this [*previous question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51713528/1260204). It is very well written because it includes a self contained table structure (**DDL**), insert **data** to populate those tables, and the **query** attempt to retrieve the data against the tables as well as **expected output**. In other words a complete [mcve]. *You* providing these same artifacts *in your question* would go a long way into others being able to help you with your question. You could also use http://rextester.com/ for your DDL and data.

Comment: If you have data that you are comfortable post from a confidential/proprietary perspective you can dump it to a CSV or Excel, generate CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements using something like [Convert CSV to SQL](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm), and post the output of that to something like [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). Like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd12bc682d308589bbd4f4912262e5ed). If your data is confidential or proprietary mock up some data in Excel and then follow the remain steps as outlined above.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful tips. I pasted some of the table contents onto Excel and then I used https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# to create the table in a tidier format. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: You still haven't shown us your desired results.

Comment: Good point. I've just added it now.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example then update your question to make the example input correspond to the example desired results *(Showing each table's example contents individually, not combine as the result of a different query)*.

Comment: What do you want to do if two CPZNames are tied for min/max in one or other type?

Comment: Not as an image please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to return the name of the CPZName with the Maximum number of Emails.

```
SELECT TOP 1 CPZName, COUNT(*) AS NumEmails
FROM [MyData]
WHERE [Type]='email'
GROUP BY CPZName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

> I'd like the results to look something like this...

For multiple items like this in the same result row, you run a separate query similar to the above as a nested/subquery for each column:

```
SELECT 
   (
       SELECT TOP 1 CPZName
       FROM [MyData]
       WHERE [Type]='email'
       GROUP BY CPZName
       ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ) As MaxEmail, 
   (
       SELECT TOP 1 CPZName
       FROM [MyData]
       WHERE [Type]='email'
       GROUP BY CPZName
       ORDER BY COUNT(*)
    ) As MinEmail, 
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps.

First, aggregate and order the results, then pick the values you're searching for.

```
WITH
  CPZName_Summary AS
(
  SELECT
    CPZName,
    Type,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY CPZName, Type
          ORDER BY COUNT(*)
    )
      AS row_asc,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY CPZName, Type
          ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    )
      AS row_desc
  FROM
    [yourData]
  GROUP BY
    CPZName,
    Type
)
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'email'  AND row_asc  = 1 THEN CPZName END)  AS MinEmail,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'email'  AND row_desc = 1 THEN CPZName END)  AS MaxEmail,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'letter' AND row_asc  = 1 THEN CPZName END)  AS MinLetter,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'letter' AND row_desc = 1 THEN CPZName END)  AS MaxLetter
FROM
  CPZName_Summary
WHERE
  Type IN ('email', 'letter')
```

Take care for when multiple CPZName's are tied with the same number of emails.  You may want to add something to the `ORDER BY` clauses to guarantee you get the ***one*** you want, or rethink the output structure so you can return multiple values in the event of ties.